# what is data-icon in html5?

Tags: html

What is "data-icon" in HTML5 and how can I use it? If you know any source where I can read more about it, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the "data-sigil" HTML attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132963/what-is-the-data-sigil-html-attribute)

Answer (score 24):

[`data-` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-html5-20121217/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) are [attributes for private use](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/). I.e., anybody can make up any `data-` attribute and do with it whatever he wants. I suppose you came across this as part of [jQuery mobile's markup for icons on buttons](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/buttons/buttons-icons.html).

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at this:
http://pictos.cc/server/

Data-icons are a way to add a background image to an element using fonts. The great benefits are that those images can be scaled and colored without loss of resolution.