# What is the "data-sigil" HTML attribute?

Tags: html

I just came across a website that has "data-sigil" as an attribute for HTML elements like `a`, `div`, `label`, `abbr`.

It accepts a string value, like this:

```
<a class="a1class" href="/more.php" data-sigil="some-description">More</a>
```

Googling ["data-sigil" HTML attribute](http://www.mail-archive.com/muldis-db-users@mm.darrenduncan.net/msg00000.html) yielded only a mailing list posting which doesn't seem to explain much in the context of an HTML attribute.

Any idea what that mysterious "data-sigil" HTML attribute could be?

Comment: Which website is it? "sigil" is a concept used in Javelin framework originally designed by folks at Facebook.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any attribute starting with `data-` is an [HTML 5 data- attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

Comment: Wow! + 1 + Accept. So this is basically a "custom data attribute" available only from HTML5 on. Cool. And Thanks.

Comment: To add further here is the official (read as, "from the horse's mouth"), documentation on this HTML5 spec for data-* attribute - http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes (The link is to the 'developer' documentation from W3C)

Answer (score 12):

It's actually a sigil from Javelin (Facebook JavaScript framework). Javelin separates style markers (ids and classes) from functional markers. They use sigils for the latter. See:

http://phabricator.com/docs/javelin/article/Concepts:_Sigils_and_Metadata.html