# What does data attribute stand for in anchor(<a>) tag in PHP?

Tags: php, html, drupal-6, query-string

I'm using Drupal CMS. I'm a newbie in Drupal and PHP.
In one of my `*.tpl.php` file I've a PHP code snippet as follows:

```
<div class="form-section">
                    <h3>Job Alerts: jobs delivered to your inbox! <strong>(optional) </strong> <span class="info-ico"><em><?php echo bfstring('tooltip_register_job_alerts'); ?></em></span></h3>                    
                    <?php $alerts = bevforce_get_user_option($user->uid, 'alert', false); ?>
                    <ul class="jobs-alerts-list">
                        <?php foreach ($alerts as $a) : ?>
                            <li><?php echo $a['value']['alert_name']; ?> <a href="#" class="edit-link tip-open"  data-oid="<?php echo $a['oid']; ?>">edit</a></li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                    <p><!--<a class="popup-loader" href="<?php echo url(); ?>?bf-ajax=create-job-alert&page=register"><strong>Create Job Alert</strong></a>-->
                    <a class="popup-loader" href="/?bf-ajax=create-job-alert&amp;page=register">Create New Job Alert</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
```

I'm not getting what's the purpose of `data-oid="<?php echo $a['oid']; ?>"` in anchor tag(`<a>`). I've never seen such attribute anywhere in `<a>` tag. 
Following is another code snippet from my PHP code :

```
<li><a class="popup-loader" href="/?bf-ajax=delete-job-alert&amp;eid=&amp;oid=0">Remove</a></li>
```

If I hover the mouse cursor over the hypertext Remove, I'm getting the following URL:

```
 xyz.com/bf-ajax=delete-job-alert&oid=3805462
```

How could this happen that I'm passing the value oid=0 in query string but it is showing some different value when I hover the hypertext? Is this happening due to the `data-oid` attribute we used in `<a>` tag above?
So in short my doubt is what's the purpose of attribute `data-oid` in `<a>` tag and how the value is getting changed from the value I set in the code?
Can anyone clear my above doubts?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is data-icon in html5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754979/what-is-data-icon-in-html5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data-*` attribute is primarily for JavaScript in HTML 5. See: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Using the jQuery library, it's really easy to reference a data attribute: `$("#someLink").data("name")` for something like `<a href="#" id="someLink" data-name="my cool link">Click Me</a>` -- the `.data("name")` is simply for `data-name`.

Comment: :Thanks for your answer. But my second doubt is still unclear that how the value of oid=0 in querystring is changing to oid=3805462? Can you help me in clearing this doubt. Thanks once again.

Comment: There's some javascript/jquery  somewhere doing this.