# What is data-target and data-slide-to attribute?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I am using bootstrap, (Ok, I am new to it), I found this two attributes, can somebody explain it to me?

Comment: [`data-*` attribute docs](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes). They're custom attributes following the HTML5 spec.

Comment: **[See their documentation.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is data-icon in html5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754979/what-is-data-icon-in-html5)

Comment: One should mention that w3schools is widely despised here on StackOverflow, mainly because they don't correct the errors they do have. Their site is popular on Google, and they are easy to read and learn from, but they're not as good as official documentation. Use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) as a more technical but also more reliable reference for web technologies.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just to carry forward the point of @Larsenal, custom data attributes could be very handy for developers. Like the spec says:

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements. These attributes are not intended for use by software that is independent of the site that uses the attributes.

**Example usage includes:**

Storing initial height/width, which might later be changed with JS. 
There are easy ways to get and set these attributes through JavaScript - using `getAttribute` and `setAttribute`.

```
 <div id='strawberry-plant' data-fruit='12'></div>
 <script>
    // 'Getting' data-attributes using getAttribute
    var plant = document.getElementById('strawberry-plant');
    var fruitCount = plant.getAttribute('data-fruit'); // fruitCount = '12'
 </script>
```

**Remember though**, this is **not** `good practice`. So, make use of `dataset properties`.

Read more about data-attributes here: http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

You would fall in love with them as a JavaScript developer (or maybe not).

Comment: No problem, @XinruiMa! Thanks for accepting the answer.. It was the first time I answered something here and glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 13):

The attributes you see are custom data attributes.  They're sometimes denoted `data-*`.

Anything with the "data-" prefix is used to store custom data that won't be rendered in the browser.

So you could have this:

```
<div data-foo="ABC" data-bar="123">Hello World</div>
```

Typically, you'd read back this data from your JavaScript and do something with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot~! All of you are great help!

Answer (score 6):

In this case, they're variables used to configure to the [carousel component](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel):

> Use data attributes to easily control the position of the carousel.
>   `data-slide` accepts the keywords `prev` or `next`, which alters the slide
>   position relative to its current position. Alternatively, use
>   `data-slide-to` to pass a raw slide index to the carousel
>   `data-slide-to="2"`, which shifts the slide position to a particular
>   index beginning with `0`.

[Read more about HTML5 `data-` attributes](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/).